# Does AWK Buffer Multiple Print Statements Before Writing Them to Disc?

Tags: performance, file, awk, printing, buffer

I have an AWK script that writes tens of thousands of pretty long lines to a couple of files and nearly ten thousand lines to a few more files on a network drive (all needed for different purposes).  I would like to make the file I/O as efficient as possible for a few reasons.

Does AWK immediately write to a file with every print(f) statement or does it buffer them?  If so, how much buffering goes on?

I am considering writing everything to a buffer (e.g., rec1 "\n" rec2 "\n" rec3...) and then dumping it all with a single print command, but not if it won't have a net benefit.

I am curious, not just for this program, but also to sharpen my "best practices" skills.  I program a lot in AWK, but haven't been able to find the answer to this, yet.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you can read in [GNU Awk manual: I/O functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html). Actually that is why `fflush` ([accepted for inclusion in POSIX](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=634)) exists: to flush the buffers. [And here some practical evidence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/591325).

Answer (score 3):

As @Quasimodo points out, yes awk buffers it's output by default and you can bypass that by inserting `fflush()` statements if you like.

For the other part of your question (`I am considering writing everything to a buffer (e.g., rec1 "\n" rec2 "\n" rec3...) and then dumping it all with a single print command, but not if it won't have a net benefit.`) - constantly appending to a variable using string concatenation in awk is roughly as slow as I/O since awk has to continually find new memory areas big enough to hold the result of the concatenation, then move the contents of the old location to the new, then append the new text, and then free up the previous area so there'd be no noticeable benefit in execution speed of buffering and then printing all at once vs just printing as you go.

Comment: Thanks for the well considered answer.  There's more to the comparison of time.  (Those memory ops should be much faster -- as long as I'm not forcing swaps.  Nonetheless, for what I'm doing, the difference isn't a deal breaker.) There are issues with Task Scheduler ignoring priority requests -- and the ones that take the biggest hit on our system have to do with file I/O.  I've already optimized just about everything else in the program to lighten the I/O load and it's working well. I was just looking to squeeze whatever speed I can out of the program.  I'll leave the buffering to AWK.

Comment: It's possible there are other opportunities for improving the efficiency of your program than I/O. If you post a new question about that with a [mcve] then we could help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm good.  The same, unaltered program ran for about 1 1/2 years under Task Scheduler and always finished in about ten minutes.  In November, something changed -- and it wasn't the program, the server (to which 3 sysadmins swore) -- or even the volume or source of data.  All of a sudden, the program was taking from 1 1/3 to over 2 *hours* when run from TS.  Day after day after day...  By eliminating as many file I/O system calls as possible, it now runs in about 20-25 seconds manually and well under 2 minutes under TS.  I am convinced TS was setting I/O threads' priority too low.